# Save Java file object as oracle Blob

Tags: java, blob

I am using play framework 2.0 and Intellij. I am trying to let a user upload a document and then I save it as a blob object in an Oracle database. 
I am using play's method to get the file from the user. Then in the controller, I send it to the model class where I save the file in the database. The problem is that the "attachment" field is always null when saving to the database and I don't know why. 
I tried reading the file object to a byte string that I then converted to a blob object (I  also converted the attachment field to be of type Blob) but that blob object was also null. How can I do this?

//CONTROLLER CODE

```
public  static Result ValidateQuestion() {
    Form<Questions> filledForm = questionForm.bindFromRequest();

    if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
        return badRequest(createQuestion.render(questionForm,fillCourseList(),fillSemesterList()));
    }
    else {
        Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart attachment = body.getFile("attachment");
        if(attachment!=null) {
            Attachmenttable.create(1, "other", attachment.getFile());
        }
        return redirect(routes.TeacherController.TeacherDashboard());
    }

}
```

//MODEL CLASS CODE

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "s_attachmenttable")
public int attachment_id;

@Constraints.Required
public int question_id;

@Constraints.Required
public String name;

@Transient
public File attachment;

public Attachmenttable(int spurning_id, String name, File attachment) {
    this.spurning_id = spurning_id;
    this.nafn = nafn;
    this.vidhengi = vidhengi;
}

public static Attachmenttable create(int question_id, String name, File attachment) {

  Attachmenttable attachmenttable = new Attachmenttable(question_id, name, attachment);
    attachmenttable.save();
    return attachmenttable;
}
```